# QGIS - how to label values of two different polygons in one polygon setting

Tags: qgis, labeling, query

I'd like to display the values of two different polygons in one. I have a polygon with the border of different states, then in a separate polygon I have the borders of districts dividing the states... so from a certain zoom factor I'd like to have the name of the District being displayed under the Name of the State, because in this case I Have more control concerning their placement.

[image: Initial situation]

After applying/altering the label settings in the district polygon, this is what I was thinking of:

[image: destination]

Comment: Are all the polygons features part in the same layer?

Comment: the district polygons are in one and the state playgons are in an other. But the geometry of (taking the example of the upper picture) of state "B" equals dissolved District 1-4 from State "B".

Comment: Use rule basel labels if you want to have different styles for states and districts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `overlay_within`:

```
'State '  || 
array_first( 
  overlay_within(layer:='State', expression:=Statename))  ||  '\n'  || 
'District ' || "Districtname"
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Combining the answer from **BERA** with **[HTML formatting](https://north-road.com/2022/09/09/mixed-format-labels-in-qgis-coming-soon/)**
we can achieve both:

1. Values from a second layer with `overlay_within`
2. Different color for each line

As follows:

```
'State: '  || 
array_first( 
  overlay_within(layer:='State', expression:=Statename))|| 
'<p><span style="color:#7f0694">' || 
'District: ' || "Districtname" ||
'</span>'
```

Make sure **'Allow HTML formatting'** is checked on.
[image: Allow HTML formatting']

The first line will get the default label colour, whereas the second line will get the span style color:
[image: example output]